# Filtering of data based on condition using matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I have `ref` value as

```
ref = [9.8 13 10.51 12.2 10.45 11.4]
```

and `In` values as

```
In = [10.7 11 11.5 11.9 12]
```

I want to do following two things :

1. Identify which `In` value closest matches with `ref` value and then after
2. To check whether the matched `In` value is lower or higher than `ref` value. If it is lower than saved in array1 and if it is higher than saved in array2

Comment: can you please post an example of the both result vectors you are expecting in the given example? It's very hard to understand what you are trying to do. Even it's confusing how overproduction and underproduction is defined.

Comment: I have made in very simple language, Please see the modified question . Now I think you would understand what I mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following code snippet as one of many solutions:

```
% it would be a much better style 
% to initialize the result vectors here properly!
a1 = [];
a2 = [];

for i=1:length(P_in)
    [value, ind] = min(abs(P_in(i) - P_ref));

    if P_in(i) <= P_ref(ind)
        a1 = [a1 P_in(i)];
    else
        a2 = [a2 P_in(i)];
    end;
end;
```

with the given vectors

```
P_ref = [9.8 13 10.51 12.2 10.45 11.4];
P_in = [10.5 11 11.5 11.9 12];
```

I get the following result:

```
array1 = [10.5000   11.0000   11.9000   12.0000]
array2 = [11.5000]
```

Comment: I guess this is the way to go if you want 'the closest match', rather than 'a close match'.

Comment: @Dennis you're right. As I understood from the question, one single result is requested. 'a close match' means several results are possible?

Comment: It is quite possible that you give the asker what he was looking for. My thought was mainly that a close match, might mean that sometimes 0 results could come back.

Comment: I have one more question how I can proceeded the same thing if 'In' and 'ref' size are different.For example if 'In' size of 20x1 while 'ref' size of 200x1  any suggestion ?

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath  Both vectors have a different size in your example ('In': 5; 'Ref': 6). So for the code example it makes no difference.

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath: has the above solution worked for you?

Comment: yes with some slight modification I have to do based on my data. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed deviation that is allowed for values to be 'close', the key part of your question can be solved with the [`ismemberf` File Exchange Submission](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23294-ismemberf).

Basic syntax:

```
[tf, loc]=ismemberf(0.3, 0:0.1:1)
```

Can be exended by defining the allowed tolerance:

```
[tf, loc]=ismemberf(0.3, 0:0.1:1, 'tol', 1.5)
```