# Indexing and obtaining the value using matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, indexing

This question is the related to my previous question [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259839/filtering-of-data-based-on-condition-using-matlab).

Once I finished on getting over and underproduction of data, There is another parameter called sigma, I have with same size as ref. Now I have done classifying the data of 'in' into under and over based on closest match of ref, How at the same time I can select sigma value ?
For example , if

```
ref = [9.8 13 10.51 12.2 10.45 11.4] ;
```

`s  = [2 3 4 6 9 10];`
   and In = [10.7 11 11.5 11.9 12]

I got output as

```
 array2 = [11.5000]
```

But I how can get its corresponding sigma value , in this case ? We will get sigma as :

```
  s= [10];
```

Comment: Questions should be self-contained and include the code that you're using, how you've tried to address your problem, and how your efforts do not match your requirements. (Although if that code was provided by someone else, correct attribution is essential.)

Comment: I have used the 'find' to find which input is greater or less than ref value. once I done I recieved the value but they are also showing me the zero in datasets where ever condition not satisfied. I am not geeting any idea how to get only those sigma values which are satisfying the condition

Comment: Now I got my answer .. Sometimes brain ignore simple concept anyway thanks for your feedback